# Transfer file programmatically using bluetooth for android version 5.0 and above

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, transfer

I want to transfer file using bluetooth, i have use ContentValues code but it not works from android version 4.1 and above, I want to create this feature for version 5.0 and above models.

I have tried following 2 things, but not works.

Code 1 : Using ContentValues (support version 4.0 and below)

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, "file://"+selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, MACAddress);
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Code 2 : not works in any of the version

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sharingIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
sharingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothShare.URI, "file://"+selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me in Android 5.1.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri );
startActivity(intent);
```

And just want to share that **BluetoothShare** may not support Android 4.0+